# flux $F=(x,2y,e^{xy})$ through region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have this flux : $F=(x,2y,e^{xy})$

and this region : $D=\{z^2-16\le x^2+y^2 \le 9\}$

Which are an hyperboloid of two-sheets and a cylinder.

Using the divergence theorem : div$(F)=3$, So I just need to calculate the volume.

Volume = $2\int_{4}^{5}(\sqrt{z^2-16})^2\pi$

**Flux** = $\displaystyle(3)2\int_{4}^{5}(\sqrt{z^2-16})^2\pi=26\pi$

Is this the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, being the divergence constant it is ok to calculate the volume. Nevertheless, I cannot follow your calculation and, anyway, it does not give the correct value. I'd proceed as follows.

The symmetry suggest to use cylindrical coordinates, so $D=\{z^2-16\le r^2 \le 9\}$ and

$\displaystyle V=\int_Dr\,\mathbb dz\,\mathbb dr\,\mathbb d\theta$

with $\theta$ ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$, $r$ from $0$ to $3$ and $z$ from $-\sqrt{r^2+16}$ to $\sqrt{r^2+16}$

$\displaystyle V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\int_{-\sqrt{r^2+16}}^{\sqrt{r^2+16}}r\,\mathbb dz\,\mathbb dr\,\mathbb d\theta=2\pi\int_0^32r\sqrt{r^2+16}\,\mathbb dr=\dfrac{244}{3}\pi$